# How to disable validation on hidden controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap in my application.

**Default.aspx**

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div id="Control1">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">DropDown Control
      </label>
      <div class="controls">
        <select data-val="true" data-val-required="Field is required" name="">
        <option value="">--Select--</option> 
        <option value=1>Value1</option>
        <option value=2>Value2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="Control2" style="display;none;">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Textbox Control
        </label>
       <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="txtId" data-val="true" data-val-required="Field is required"/>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>   
<button id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="Submit();">
  Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: "hidden"
  });

  function Submit() {
    if (!$('#Form1').valid()) {
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here i need to validate only the `Control1` div. I dont want to validate hidden div `(Control2)`, but it is getting validated.

I'm using

```
js/jquery.validate.min.js
js/uncompressed/jquery.validate.js
js/uncompressed/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
```

Please help me.

Comment: Remove the class and `data-val-required` attributes from that from you want to remove the validation.

Comment: Set it to `ignore: "#txtId"` to ignore that field, as it's not really hidden when a parent element is not displayed.

Comment: Also, the default is `ignore : ':hidden'` and as jQuery's `not()` selector is used, that should work as well, so just removing the ignore rule you already have should also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this:
ignore: '#hidden'  worked for me

```
$("#myform").validate({
    ignore: "#hidden"
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

`ignore: ':hidden'` worked for me.

```
$("#myForm").validate({ 
    ignore: ':hidden', 
    submitHandler: function( form ) {
        //To do
    }
});
```

This ignored required validation only when the field was hidden.
Hope this helps.

Comment: If the field was hidden by jQuery .hidden() it works like charm :-)

Answer (score 2):

Refer this..

```
$(formSelector).bootstrapValidator({
excluded: [':disabled', ':hidden', ':not(:visible)'],
feedbackIcons: {
    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
},
live: 'enabled',
message: 'This value is not valid',
submitButtons: 'button[type="submit"]',
trigger: null,
fields: ...
});
```

For More information go to [Bootstrap Validation Setting](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/settings/)

Answer (score -1):

Set the validation control's Enabled property to false.

```
CausesValidation="False"
```